# conflito com googleapis jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Estou a importar várias apis para no mesmo site, o problema é algumas deixam de trabalhar. Por exemplo, uma api para fazer um autocomplete, outra para fazer um efeito no menu e outra para uma caixa de feedback. Há alguma maneira de contornar estes conflitos? estou a chama-las da seguinte maneira:

No footer tenho o seguinte:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/layerslider/js/jquerytransit.js"></script>
<script src="js/layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>

<script src="js/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blackandwhite.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.touchswipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="changer/js/changer.js"></script>
```

No header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/layerslider/css/layerslider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
```

Para o autocomplete, também se encontra no header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Estou usando o [autocomplete do jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não dá para rodar várias versões diferentes do jQuery numa mesma página. Escolha apenas uma delas, de preferência a mais recente:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Outras dicas e recomendações:

- A **ordem** dos `<script>` faz diferença. Sempre inclua o jQuery **antes** do jQuery UI ou outras bibliotecas que dependam dele.
- Existe um [Download Builder para o jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/download/), onde você pode escolher quais efeitos você deseja, que todos eles serão incluídos num único arquivo `.js` para você incluir na sua página.

---

Mantenha os stylesheets no header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/layerslider/css/layerslider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
```

E os scripts no footer:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blackandwhite.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.touchswipe.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/layerslider/js/jquerytransit.js"></script>
<script src="js/layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>
<script src="js/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js"></script>

<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="changer/js/changer.js"></script>
```

Eu apenas re-ordenei, e removi o jQuery duplicado. O jQuery precisa vir antes de tudo, pois os demais scripts dependem dele. Por isso é o primeiro que aparece.

Comment: mas sendo assim vou perder funcionalidades, certo?

Comment: Não. Você só precisa de um jQuery.

Comment: Por outro lado, talvez as bibliotecas que você esteja a carregar tenham algum conflito entre si ou exijam versões diferentes do jQuery. Não dá para adivinhar sem saber exatamente quais são. Edite a sua pergunta, incluindo TODOS os `<script>`, pois não somos videntes... pelo menos eu não sou. :-)

Comment: obrigado! já editei. Mas ao substituir apenas por um, houver funcionalidades que deixaram de trabalhar

Comment: Agora só não trabalha o autocomplete. O código do autocomplete está no header e o restante no footer. há problemas se estiver por essa ordem?

Comment: Você está confundindo as coisas. Você só precisa de um `<script>` para a biblioteca jQuery. E vai precisar de um `<script>` para cada biblioteca adicional. Eu pedi para você incluir os `<script>` de **TODAS** as biliotecas que está a incluir, e não de uma só, para que a gente veja o que você está fazendo  de errado, e possamos mostrar o jeito certo.

Comment: Entenda: quanto mais código você postar, melhor. :-) Ajude-nos a te ajudar.

Comment: ja editei, obrigado por continuar a ajudar!

Comment: agora só o autocomplete é que não funciona. O menu e seus efeitos e uma barra de feedback já trabalham.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Por favor, verifique se a sugestão funciona.

Comment: já verifiquei. ficou tudo a trabalhar! obrigado e um abraço! :)